# Is it natural and correct to say "live better" in the sense of having a better life?

Tags: phrase-choice

Is it natural and correct to say "live better" in the sense of having a better life?

> Peaple often emigrate to **live better**.

I am trying to say is that people emigrate to seek a better life.

Comment: What you're *trying to say is that people emigrate to **seek a better a life*** - which imho is far more "natural" than ***...to live better***. In short, stick with what you already know, and don't bother about coming up with alternatives. But I would also add that the *most* idiomatic form might actually be *People often emigrate [**for** a better life*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22emigrate+for+a+better+life%22)

Comment: ...ooops - cut&pasted your typo, which I hadn't noticed. Should be *people emigrate to **seek a better life*** (no article before ***life***).

Comment: I agree with 'seek a better life' and 'for a better life' in that context. There was an advertising slogan for General Electric Co. in the 1950's, "Live better electrically." The phrase 'live better' is succinct and good for advertising slogans and the names of organisations.